# Textview wordwrap not on space in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout, word-wrap

I have a TextView in a RelativeLayout which just keeps cutting the text in the middle of the word.

What is the reason for the behavior?

What I have:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-35dp" >
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtThema_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtThema_titel"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:text="Some random text that will be longer than this text. Data comes from SQLite-Database" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What it produces:

```
Some random text that wil
l be longer than this 
text. Data comes from SQL
ite-Database
```

Some words are on the next line like 'text' in this example, some get cut somewhere in the word.

My text comes from an SQLite-database, when I use static text the wrapping is ok.

What can I check my text for? The spaces look like regular spaces... 
The padding does not change anything.

**UPDATE** 
After spending some time checking the character which looks like a space I finally found the correspindonding hex code on http://www.ascii-code.com/

The problem went away using replaceAll

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\u00a0"," ");
```

Maybe someone knows a good way to avoid the behavior for the TextView different...